# Casting a pointer to an int

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, heap-memory, sbrk

I am writing my own functions for `malloc` and `free` in C for an assignment. I need to take advantage of the C `sbrk()` wrapper function. From what I understand `sbrk()` increments the program's data space by the number of bytes passed as an argument and points to the location of the program break.

If I have the following code snippet:

`#define BLOCK_SIZE 20`

`int x;`

`x = (int)sbrk(BLOCK_SIZE + 4);`

I get the compiler error `warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size`. Why is this and is there anyway I can cast the address pointed to by `sbrk()` to an `int`?

Comment: Is there any reason not to use `void *x;` ?   If you really want an integral type there is `intptr_t x = (intptr_t)sbrk...;` from `<stdint.h>`

Comment: Because int is 32 bits, pointer is 64 bits. try use long int. try check sizeof(int) and sizeof(void*)

Answer (score 14):

> I get the compiler error warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size.
> Why is this

Because pointer and `int` may have different length, for example, on 64-bit system, `sizeof(void *)` (i.e. length of pointer) usually is 8, but `sizeof(int)` usually is 4. In this case, if you cast a pointer to an `int` and cast it back, you will get a invalid pointer instead of the original pointer.

> and is there anyway I can cast the address pointed to by sbrk() to an int?

If you really need to cast a pointer to an integer, you should cast it to an `intptr_t` or `uintptr_t`, from `<stdint.h>`.

---

From `<stdint.h>(P)`:

> - Integer types capable of holding object pointers
>
> The following type designates a signed integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to a pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: `intptr_t`
>
> The  following  type designates an unsigned integer type with the property that any valid pointer to void can be converted to this type, then converted back to a pointer to void, and the result will compare equal to the original pointer: `uintptr_t`
>
> On XSI-conformant systems, the `intptr_t` and `uintptr_t` types are required; otherwise, they are optional.

Comment: I tried casting it to an `intptr_t` and it compiled. The reason I'm trying to cast it to an `int` is so that I can see if there is any more space left on the heap. If in my code snippet above, x is less than 0, then there is no more space on the heap.