# Assigning pointers of different type to existing memory

Tags: c

I tried to write a type agnostic `mem_take`.
It would take a peace of preallocated memory and assign its chunks to several pointers. Those pointers could point to different types: floats, doubles, etc.

```
unsigned int mem_take( void** mem_input, void** mem_pos, const int size_bytes, const int alignment )
{
    // get address
    unsigned int addr = (unsigned int)*mem_pos;

    // align
    unsigned int adjustment_bytes = 0;
    unsigned int misalignment = addr % alignment;
    if(misalignment != 0)
    {
        adjustment_bytes = alignment - misalignment;
        addr += adjustment_bytes;
    }

    // take aligned address
    *mem_input = (void*)addr;

    // move current position to next free location
    addr += size_bytes;
    *mem_pos = (void*)addr;

    // return bytes taken
    return (size_bytes + adjustment_bytes);
}
```

Example:

```
main()
{
    char mem[SOME_SIZE];
    void* mem_pos = mem;

    float*  f;
    double* d;
    int bytes_taken_f = mem_take((void**)&f , &mem_pos, 2 * sizeof(float) , 8); // 2 floats
    int bytes_taken_d = mem_take((void**)&d , &mem_pos, 3 * sizeof(double), 8); // 3 doubles
    // etc.

    // now free to use the memory via arrays
    f[0] = 1.0f;
    f[1] = 2.0f;

    d[0] = 1.0f;
    d[1] = 2.0f;
    d[2] = 3.0f;
}
```

The reason why this is done is the platform - a DSP processor, where memory is very limited. (Long story.)

Is this solution valid? Is `mem_take` written properly?

p.s.
Note, real use case is a fixed point DSP processor, so the above example is "simplified" in a way that types will not be float, double, but ones specific to the processor.

Comment: use unsigned long addr = (unsigned long)*mem_pos

Comment: This would fit better in CodeReview stack exchange site, as it's working code that you want suggestions and comments on, rather than a 'programming problem'. But generally looks ok to me! :)

Comment: This is not strictly-conforming at all. It breaks strict aliasing. Also, `void **` is *not* a generic pointer type - even the requirement of an explicit cast will tell you that you're doing something suspicious. Therefore we cannot comment anything at all without knowing exactly the compiler implementation that you're using.

Comment: Maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/22624888/4386427 could be interesting for you

Comment: Let's say the compiler is GCC 7.3.

Comment: `unsigned int`is not the right type to hold an address in integer form. Use `intptr_t` for that. Similar `unsigned int` is not the right type to hold the number of bytes or aligment. Use a `size_t` for that.

Answer (score 0):

Doing:

```
 void f(void **f);
 float a;
 f((void**)&a);
```

is not a good idea, cause `void**` is not portable. You need to take the address of `void*` variable:

```
 void f(void **f);
 float a;
 void *tmp = &a;
 f(&tmp);
```

, but you can return `void*` just like malloc!
It's like writing simple malloc function which allocated memory on custom stack.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

void *mem_take(void **mem, size_t *memsize, size_t nmemb, size_t size, size_t alignment, size_t *bytes_to_take)
{
    assert(mem != NULL);
    assert(nmemb != 0); // we can't "free"
    assert(size != 0);
    assert(alignment != 0);

    // get array size
    const size_t s = nmemb * size;
    if (nmemb != 0 && s / nmemb != size) {
        // overflow!
        return NULL;
    }

    // align
    const size_t rest = (size_t)((uintptr_t)*mem % alignment);
    const size_t alignmentadd = rest == 0 ? 0 : alignment - rest;
    // fprintf(stderr, "alignment %d %d %d %d\n", alignmentadd, ((uintptr_t)*mem % alignment), *memsize, s);

    // inform of bytes we need to take
    if (bytes_to_take != NULL) {
        *bytes_to_take = alignmentadd + s;
    }

    // check free memory
    if (*memsize < alignmentadd + s) {
        //fprintf(stderr, "ENOMEM %d %d %d \n", *memsize, alignmentadd, s);
        // ENOMEM!
        return NULL;
    }

    // update state, get s + alignmentadd bytes, return ret
    char *memc = *mem;
    memc += alignmentadd;
    void * const ret = memc;
    memc += s;
    *mem = memc;
    *memsize -= alignmentadd + s;

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    #define SOME_SIZE  (sizeof(float) * 2 + 3 * sizeof(double) + 8)
    char mem[SOME_SIZE];
    void *mem_pos = mem;
    size_t memsize = sizeof(mem);

    float  *f = mem_take(&mem_pos, &memsize, 2, sizeof(float), 8, NULL); // 2 floats
    assert(f != NULL);
    double *d = mem_take(&mem_pos, &memsize, 3, sizeof(double), 8, NULL); // 3 doubles
    assert(d != NULL);
    // etc.

    // now free to use the memory via arrays
    f[0] = 1.0f;
    f[1] = 2.0f;

    d[0] = 1.0f;
    d[1] = 2.0f;
    d[2] = 3.0f;

    printf("%f %f %lf %lf %lf\n", f[0], f[1], d[0], d[1], d[2]);
}
```